# Sharepoint Server 2019 empty <body> tags

Tags: sharepoint, updates

I have this problem: After installing the KB5002000 (Security Update for MSSP 2019 Core) patch, I only see the first page. The subpages are empty and I can see code in the page source, but the  tag is empty.

```
</script></html>
<body>

</body><script type="text/javascript" nonce="119d1fbe-6374-4139-8f43-a416d4e9a6f1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered the very same issue on our sharepoint installation and your post gave me the clue i needed to fix the issue. So it's only fair i share my solution.

After installing the optional KB5002001 update, Sharepoint now works as expected.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/august-10-2021-update-for-sharepoint-server-2019-language-pack-kb5002001-6fc0f901-7eba-41c5-8488-b65d5cefd718

Microsoft in their infinite wisdom decided to only offer this update as a manual download and not through Windows update.

Didn't even have to reboot the system.